# how to find highest and second highest number in an array without using max function

Tags: php, arrays

I already have solution. But i think it will be more optimizable. So please provide me a solution for it. And remember that don't use predefined function of php. Like max() function.
i know there are so many ways to find it but i want best and better solution. Because my array contains more than 1 lakh records and it's taking lot of time. Or sometime site will be down.

My code :

```
<?php 

$array = array('1', '15', '2','10',4);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($array);
echo "<pre>";
$max = 0;
$s_max=0;

for($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++)
{
    $a = $array[$i];
    $tmax = $max;
    $ts_max = $s_max;
    if($a > $tmax && $a > $ts_max)
    {
        $max = $a;
        if($tmax > $ts_max) {
            $s_max = $tmax;
        } else {
            $s_max = $ts_max;
        }
    } else if($tmax > $a && $tmax > $ts_max)
    {
        $max = $tmax;
        if($a > $ts_max) {
            $s_max = $a;
        } else {
            $s_max = $ts_max;
        }
    } else if($ts_max > $a && $ts_max > $tmax)
    {
        $max = $ts_max;
        if($a > $tmax)
        {
            $s_max = $a;
        } else {
            $s_max = $tmax;
        }
    }
}
echo "Max=".$max;
    echo "<br />";
    echo "S_max=".$s_max;
    echo "<br />";

?>
```

Comment: Can there be duplicate values in the array? Also, why on earth do you not want to use built-in functions?

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen, I think built-in functions make things too easy. I think he want's a challenge. Good on ya man!...but I guess it's homework; lost all respect...

Comment: Your code looks unnecessarily complicated... How would you do it with pen and paper? Try to imagine it and then implement it in code.

Comment: "Sverri M. Olsen" Please give your solution.

Comment: Copying other people's work is called cheating. If you are unable to come up with a creative way of solving this problem then maybe you should choose something else to study.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I absolutely agree with you. But given his code works (which I didn't check) it's at least better than those proposed sorting answers. Sorting is in O(nlog(n)), his is in O(n).

Comment: Sort the array..  If you can't/won't use the built in functions (and why wouldn't you?) then there's nothing stopping you implementing bubblesort or quicksort or anything else you can think of

Answer (score 8):

```
<?php 
$array = array('200', '15','69','122','50','201');
$max_1 = $max_2 = 0;

for ($i=0; $i<count($array); $i++) {
    if ($array[$i] > $max_1) {
      $max_2 = $max_1;
      $max_1 = $array[$i];
    } else if ($array[$i] > $max_2 && $array[$i] != $max_2) {
      $max_2 = $array[$i];
    }
}
echo "Max=".$max_1;
echo "<br />"; 
echo "Smax 2=".$max_2;
```

Answer (score 6):

See this solution.

```
<?php 

 $numbers = array_unique(array(1,15,2,10,4)); 
// rsort : sorts an array in reverse order (highest to lowest).

 rsort($numbers); 

 echo 'Highest is -'.$numbers[0].', Second highest is -'.$numbers[1];

 // O/P: Highest is -15, Second highest is -10
 ?>
```

Comment: without using php functions ?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't check your solution, but in terms of complexity it's IMO optimal. If the array has no more structural information (like it's sorted) there's no way to skip entries. I.e. the best solution is in O(n) which your solution is.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect and shortest code to find out the second largest value from the array. The below code will always return values in case the array contains only a value.

```
Example 1.
    $arr = [5, 8, 1, 9, 24, 14, 36, 25, 78, 15, 37];
    asort($arr);
    $secondLargestVal = $arr[count($arr)-1];

    //this will return 37

Example 2.

    $arr = [5];
    asort($arr);
    $secondLargestVal = $arr[count($arr)-1];
    //this will return 5
```

Comment: It is fine!. I think we can $arr[count($arr)-2], if we have only 2 values in the array. I hope it make sense

Comment: please explain more.

Comment: using native is good, but I don't this kind of answer will be accepted during the interview.

Comment: Yes, you are right but the person asked about the best solution and as programming, it's also important to think about execution time, memory consumption, and future fixes and practically this kind of practice are best because if code is short that's mean you can do the fixes more easily with more stability. So such kind of thing depends on how smart you are to make yourself productive by doing stable coding instead of creating a program that is not fully tested under all the aspects.

Comment: It is unnecessary to sort the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array(80,250,30,40,90,10,50,60,50);            // 250  2-times
$max = $max2 = 0;

foreach ($array as $key =>$val) {
    if ($max < $val) {
        $max2 = $max;
        $max = $val;        
    } elseif ($max2 < $val && $max != $val) {
        $max2 = $val;
    }
}

echo "Highest Value is : " . $max . "<br/>";           //output: 250
echo "Second highest value is : " . $max2 . "<br/>";   //output: 90
```

Comment: Hi, you should format your code better and include some comments besides it

Comment: This unexplained answer is just a retread of [this earlier posted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26448941/2943403), right?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use techniques in sorting like Bubble sort

```
function bubble_Sort($my_array )
{
    do
    {
        $swapped = false;
        for( $i = 0, $c = count( $my_array ) - 1; $i < $c; $i++ )
        {
            if( $my_array[$i] > $my_array[$i + 1] )
            {
                list( $my_array[$i + 1], $my_array[$i] ) =
                        array( $my_array[$i], $my_array[$i + 1] );
                $swapped = true;
            }
        }
    }
    while( $swapped );
return $my_array;
}

$test_array = array(3, 0, 2, 5, -1, 4, 1);
echo "Original Array :\n";
echo implode(', ',$test_array );
echo "\nSorted Array\n:";
echo implode(', ',bubble_Sort($test_array)). PHP_EOL;

Original Array :                                                    
3, 0, 2, 5, -1, 4, 1                                                
Sorted Array :                                                      
-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
```

Flow explanation
[image]

Comment: Sorting the entire array is not necessary for this task.  This answer performs unnecessary processing.

Answer (score -1):

The answer given by "Kanishka Panamaldeniya" is fine for highest value but will fail on second highest value i.e. if array has 2-similar highest value, then it will showing both Highest and second highest value same. I have sorted out it by adding one more level comparsion and it works fine.

```
$array = array(50,250,30,250,40,70,10,50); // 250  2-times
$max=$max2=0;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
if ($array[$i] > $max) {
    $max2 = $max;
    $max = $array[$i];
} else if (($array[$i] > $max2) && ($array[$i] != $max)) {
    $max2 = $array[$i];
}
}
echo "Highest Value is : " . $max . "<br/>"; //output : 250
echo "Second highest value is : " . $max2 . "<br/>"; //output : 70
```

Comment: This answer does not find a "second highest" value when all values are the same.  Worse, it fabricates a values that does not even exist in the input. https://3v4l.org/3nhv1

Answer (score -1):

This code will return second max value from array

```
$array = array(80,250,30,250,40,90,10,50,60,50); // 250  2-times
$max=$max2=0;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
    if($i == 0) {
        $max2 = $array[$i];
    }
     
    if($array[$i] > $max) {
        $max = $array[$i];
    }
    
    if($max > $array[$i] && $array[$i] > $max2) {
        $max2 = $array[$i];
    }
}    


echo "Highest Value is : " . $max . "<br/>"; //output : 250
echo "Second highest value is : " . $max2 . "<br/>"; //output : 90
```

Comment: Watch this answer fail with different, realistic, simple input data: https://3v4l.org/BblpJ

Answer (score -1):

```
Two way find the second highest salary 
1. Sort the data in Descending order
2. get array first value
3. Check the condition already comments

$array =  [2,3,6,11,17,14,19];
$max   =  $array[0];
$count =  count($array);
for($i=0; $i<$count;$i++)
{
      for($j=$i+1;$j<$count;$j++)
      {
         if($array[$i] < $array[$j])
         {
            $temp = $array[$i];
            $array[$i] = $array[$j];
            $array[$j] = $temp;
         }
      }
}

First Method
//echo $array[1]; // Second highest value

$second ='';
for($k=0;$k<2;$k++)
{
    if($array[$k] >$max)
    {
        $second = $array[$k];       
    }
}
echo $second; // Second method
```

Comment: Symmetric Array Destructuring removes the need for `$temp` in modern programming. It is unnecessary to sort the entire payload.

Answer (score -1):

Without using MAX function. Here.

```
$arr = [3,4,-5,-3,1,0,4,4,4];
rsort($arr); // SORT ARRAY IN DESCENDING ORDER

$largest = $arr[0]; // IN DESCENDING ORDER THE LARGEST ELEMENT IS ALWAYS THE FIRST ELEMENT

$secondLargest = 0;

foreach($arr as $val){
    $secondLargest = $val; // KEEP UPDATING THE VARIABLE WITH THE VALUE UNTIL IT RECEIVES THE FIRST ELEMENT WHICH IS DIFFERENT FROM THE LARGEST VALUE
    
    if($val != $arr[0]){
        break; // BREAK OUT OF THE LOOP AS SOON AS THE VALUE IS DIFFERENT THAN THE LARGEST ELEMENT
    }
}

echo $secondLargest;
```